# OpenMAX and the NDK: Where I can get the surface?

Tags: c++, android-ndk, openmax

I'm writing an application that shows video. The application is written using the Android NDK and JNI.

I want to use OpenMAX. In the OpenMAX example, it retrieves the surface from Java, but where I can get the surface to render? I can get a nativeWindow only through applicationContext.

Example:

```
void Java_com_example_nativemedia_NativeMedia_setSurface(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jobject surface)                
{   
    theNativeWindow = ANativeWindow_fromSurface(env, surface);  
}
```

But I don't have the surface.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The surface is retrieved from the SurfaceHolder that is passed in as a parameter in the methods in [SurfaceHolder.Callback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback.html), ie `surfaceChanged` or `surfaceCreated`.

Look for where the JNI function `setSurface` is called by Java:

[wilhelm\tests\native-media\src\com\example\nativemedia\NativeMedia.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/wilhelm/+/738e761c42f146b655fa01707b82be25c2200d63/tests/native-media/src/com/example/nativemedia/NativeMedia.java)

Comment: but . i dont have a surfaceView. where i can get surfaceHolder. example on java + c++  . application only on c++. i may create surfaceview on c++ with jni?

Comment: Constantine, are you writing a 100% native C++ app? Are you using NativeActivity? If so then according to [NativeActivity docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html) you should be able to implement [SurfaceHolder.Callback2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback2.html) and get a SurfaceHolder.